# How to return just the value of a string in C?

Tags: c, string

How can I make a function in C that just returns the value of the string passed to it, for instance in the example given in main(), I would like to "normalize" the string "wACkY!" to just "Wacky!". I have managed to do this with a void function that directly modifies the string at its memory location, but what I want to do is not modify the string itself, but just return a modified version of it.

#### How can I do this?

```
printf("%s\n", normalize(string));
```

#### My normalize function

```
char *normalize(char *a) {
printf("%s\n", a);
int i = 0;
a[i] = toupper(a[i]);
for (i = 1; a[i] != '\0'; ++i) {
    a[i] = tolower(a[i]);
}
return a;
}
```

### In main()

```
char *string = "wACkY!";
printf("%s\n", string);
printf("%s\n", normalize(string));
```

Comment: C doesn't have a string type; C only has character arrays.

Comment: And your invoke from `main` to the existing function shouldn't work anyway unless your implementation is being particularly generous. That's a read-only string-literal addressed by a non-const pointer, and passed to a function attempting to modify it in-place. [**Don't do that**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/164194/why-do-i-get-a-segmentation-fault-when-writing-to-a-string-initialized-with-cha), regardless of the answer to this question.

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a new heap memory with the size of the string that you have passed, please consider addition +1 for '\0' character. Use malloc, or calloc.
2. Use memcpy or strncpy to write on the new heap memory.
3. Make changes to the new memory using whatever you have done with the normalize function.
4. And return the new char *

Comment: I did it. It worked. But what happen to the new string that I made using malloc. Is there a way to free that memory after it has been returned using the function return?

Comment: Yes. save the return dynamically allocated and modified char * (which is a string!) to a variable. And you can free the variable. However, if you use printf("%s\n", normalize(string)); in such case the memory location will be orphaned, meaning, not freed for reuse.

so better, do the following:

char * modifiedString = normalize(string);
printf("%s\n", modifiedString);
free(modifiedString);

All the best

Comment: sorry about the indentation! In comments they do not allow such things.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this without using `malloc()`, and thus avoiding potential memory leaks, by employing VLAs, and changing the function prototype of `normalize()` to accept an additional argument that is an array for the new string.

In the program below, a character array, `newstring[]`, is declared in `main()` after finding its size by finding the length of `string` using `strlen()` and adding space for the `'\0'` terminator. Note that the function `normalize()` modifies the character array `newstring[]` through the pointer `to`, so that after the function call the effects can be seen in `newstring[]` within `main()`. But `newstring[]` also returns a pointer to the first character in `newstring[]`, allowing the string resulting from calling `normalize()` to be printed directly by `printf()`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

char * normalize(char *to, char *from)
{
    strcpy(to, from);

    for (size_t i = 0; from[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        to[i] = tolower(from[i]);
    }

    to[0] = toupper(to[0]);

    return to;
}

int main(void)
{
    char *string = "wACkY!";
    size_t newstring_sz = strlen(string) + 1;
    char newstring[newstring_sz];

    printf("%s\n", string);    
    normalize(newstring, string);
    printf("%s\n", newstring);

    /* Alternatively */
    string = "wACkY!";
    printf("%s\n", string);    
    printf("%s\n", normalize(newstring, string));

    return 0;
}
```

Program output:

```
wACkY!
Wacky!
wACkY!
Wacky!
```

Comment: There is no point returning a char * (my opinion) for the normalize free-function. Because you are already returning by updating the char *to. 

So a better software engineering would be to use void type return.

Comment: @Ehsan-- I disagree. 1) Returning a pointer allows the return value to be used directly, in `printf()` for example. 2) Returning a pointer allows the function to return `NULL` if function input is deemed incorrect for some reason or in case of error within the function. Consider that many library functions, e.g., `fgets()`, return a pointer to the modified buffer. In general, I find returning such a pointer to be a useful feature.

Comment: Yes! You are right! Under such circumstance, I do agree with you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write a function that either receives a buffer from the caller to place the modified string in, or allocates new memory for the modified string that it returns.

Although it wouldn't be difficult to provide you with this function, I feel you should do it yourself as a learning excercise. To allocate new memory for the string to return, look at `malloc()`.

Answer (score -1):

I think that a more flexible approach is when the function gets the target string as a parameter and performs copying of the source string.

Here is shown how it can look

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

char * copy_normalized( char *s1, const char *s2 )
{
    char *p = s1;

    while ( isspace( ( unsigned char )*s2 ) ) *p++ = *s2++;

    *p = toupper( ( unsigned char )*s2 );

    while ( *s2 ) *++p = tolower( ( unsigned char )*++s2 );

    return s1;
}   

int main( void ) 
{
    char s[] = "wACkY!";
    char t[sizeof( s )];

    puts( s );
    puts( copy_normalized( t, s ) );

    printf( "\n" );

    char *p = malloc( sizeof( s ) );

    puts( s );
    puts( copy_normalized( p, s ) );

    free( p );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
wACkY!
Wacky!

wACkY!
Wacky!
```

You can add a check that the character that should be converted to upper case is an alpha character.

Comment: There is no point returning a char * (my opinion) for the normalize free-function. Because you are already returning by updating the char *to. So a better software engineering would be to use void type return.

Just my view!

Comment: @Ehsan All C standard string functions confirm this convention. This allows to chain in one statement several calls of string functions. So user-defined functions also should follow this convention.